# I'm writing a simple version minesweeper in c in visual studio, but something wrong with it

Tags: arrays, c, visual-studio

the problem is that once the function set_mine is over, values in board1 all changed suddenly  just like this:

[at this time set_mine is almost over](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0H1B.png)

[set_mine was over and it came to the function display and all values just suddenly changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIn1T.png)

I do not know how this happened and why.

and this is my code:

**game.h:**

```
#pragma once
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define ROW 2
#define COL 2
#define ROWS ROW+2
#define COLS COL+2
void initial(char board[ROWS][COLS], int row, int col,char set);
void display(char board[ROW][COL], int row, int col);
void set_mine(char board[ROW][COL], int row, int col);
void find_mine(char board1[ROWS][COLS], char board2[ROWS][COLS], int row, int col);
```

**test.c:**

```
#include "game.h"

void menu()
{
    printf("****************\n");
    printf("*****1.start****\n");
    printf("*****0.exit ****\n");
    printf("****************\n");
}


int main()
{
    int input = 0;
    do {
        menu();
        printf("start or exit:");
        scanf("%d", &input);
        switch (input)
        {
        case(1):
            game();
            break;
        case(0):
            printf("the game is closed");
            break;
        default:
            printf("input again");
        }
    } while (1);
    return 0;
}
```

**game.c:**

```
#include "game.h"

void initial(char board[ROWS][COLS], int row, int col,char set)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            board[i][j] = set;
        }
    }
}

void display(char board[ROW][COL],int row, int col)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i <= row; i++)
    {
        printf("%d  ", i);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 1; i <= row; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", i);
        for (j = 1; j <= col; j++)
        {
            printf(" %c ", board[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void set_mine(char board1[ROW][COL], int row, int col)
{
    int count=0, i,j;
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    while (count < 3)
    {
        i = rand() % row+1;
        j = rand() % col+1;
        if (board1[i][j]=='0')
        {
            board1[i][j] = '1';
            count++;
        }
    }
}



void game()
{
    char board1[ROWS][COLS];
    char board2[ROWS][COLS];
    initial(board1,ROWS,COLS,'0');
    initial(board2,ROWS,COLS, '*');
    display(board2,ROW,COL);
    set_mine(board1,ROW,COL);
    display(board1,ROW,COL);
    find_mine(board1,board2,ROWS,COLS);
}
```

Comment: Posting output text as text here is better than posting text as a picture someplace else.

Comment: Post input used.

Answer (score 0):

At least this problem.

**Wrong size array**

Code is passing a `char board1[ROWS][COLS]` to functions expecting `char board[ROW][COL]`.  All but the first dimension must match and `COL != COLS`.

Save time - Enable all warnings.

---

Recommended fix: use the same size array everywhere.  Adjust loops as needed.

Also, instead of `i,j` for rows and columns indexing, use `r,c`.

Minor: calling `srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));` *once*, at code beginning, is better than possible repeated calls.